# python autocomplete skip and just call function

Tags: python, autocomplete, gtk

I have a little GUI that has an autocomplete set up like this:

```
    completion_liststore = create_completion_model()
    completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
    completion.set_model(completion_liststore)
    completion.set_text_column(0)
    completion.set_match_func(match_anywhere, None)
    builder.get_object('student_change').set_completion(completion)
    completion.connect('match-selected', self.populate_main)
```

The completion model and matching look like this in my handler class:

```
def create_completion_model():
    db = sqlite3.connect('gradebook.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from students')
    students = cursor.fetchall()
    names = Gtk.ListStore(str)
    for student in students:
        names.append([student[5]])
    cursor.close()
    return names


def match_anywhere(completion, entrystr, iter, data):
    modelstr = completion.get_model()[iter][0]
    return entrystr in modelstr.lower()
```

Pretty straight forward and works well.  What I would like to do is just call my populate_main function directly, but it only seems to work through my autocomplete.  My populate_main function looks like:

```
    def populate_main(self, completion, treemodel, treeiter):
        name = treemodel[treeiter][completion.get_text_column()]
        db = sqlite3.connect('gradebook.db')
        db.row_factory = dict_factory
        cursor = db.cursor()
        t = (name,)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * from students WHERE name=?', t)
        .... <-- and so on, filling in my form
```

is there a way to reuse this function without just copy/pasting into a new function and just sending the name to the function

Comment: What's the problem when you try to call `populate_main`?

Comment: Well, I guess the idea is, on the autocomplete, I pass a treemodel, from which I parse the name of the student. But I would like to just send the name sometimes (not using the autocomplete), skipping the treemodel stuff.  Never mind, I think that I figured it out.  I'll try it and post back.

Comment: Well, I ended up just duplicating the function with the top changing to        def populate_main_directly(self):   and then using a global.  Whatever.  Ugly but works.